# How can I show the title in inside a DIV?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to move the title upper inside of the pic.I'm created an div but it doesn't appear correctly.Then I remove.I changed to code of the existing div.

[image: This is what I want.] but show [image: this]. I tried margin-top but not work.

CSS

```
  .lazy-enabled #main-content .first-news img {
    height: 310px;
}

.lazy-enabled #main-content .first-news .tie-appear.post-thumbnail a{
    background-color: red !important;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}
```

Div PHP

```
<div id="baslist">


                        <div class="post-thumbnail">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'tie-medium' ); ?>
                                <span class="fa overlay-icon"></span>
                            </a>


                    <h2 class="post-box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
                    <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>



.lazy-enabled #main-content .first-news .tie-appear.post-thumbnail a{
    background-color: red !important;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the thumbnail wrapper to be `position: relative`, and the title to be `position: absolute`. Then you can put it on the bottom of the wrapper and add whatever margins you require.

```css
.post-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}
.post-thumbnail .post-box-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}
.post-thumbnail .post-box-title a {
    background-color: red !important;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="baslist">
  <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#" rel="bookmark">
        <span class="fa overlay-icon"></span>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
    </a>
    <h2 class="post-box-title"><a href="#" rel="bookmark">Post Title</a></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` to position it at the top of relatively positioned div

Comment: Not work in div.

Comment: It does. You only have to do it right. The outer div is relative. The inside span or div is absolute.